# Micrometer @LoadBalanced Webclient "losing" traceparent header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, micrometer, distributed-tracing

I use the following configuration for my Webclient:

`@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                  .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder()))
                    .build());
}`
```

This Webclient is being used to call another Service. Unfortunately, the request does not contain the traceparent header.

If I change the Webclient-Configuration and change it to a non-loadbalanced WebClient, it works perfectly.

How can I fix it?
It seems like the loadbalancer is not redirecting the http headers to the service.

1.) Changed Configuration to WebClient (not loadbalanced) => Works as expected, but it needs to be LoadBalanced.